# iphone 3gs memory warning calling query

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios4, iphone-3gs

hi i just want to know this: When will iphone 3gs and iphone 4 send out memory warnings

i mean after how much memory our app uses does the both devices send warnings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not strictly defined but Apple suggests you don't use more than 24MB of graphical memory as overuse of graphical memory is typically why an application receives a low memory warning.
The only good way to manage *critical low memory situations* on the iPhone is to implement the `didReceiveLowMemoryWarning` delegate methods and release as much memory as possible at that point. This means for instance:

1. All non-visible images currently loaded in memory
2. All view controllers and their subviews if not in use

This can of course be done safely provided your application is able to reload that information at a later stage. `didReceiveLowMemoryWarning` is however a last resort situation for your application.

To avoid getting to that point it is recommended to only load resources lazily i.e. when and only when you need them, and release them when they are no longer needed (for instance implementing `viewDidUnload` on all your controllers).

Comment: You are wrong. iPhone 4 has 512 RAM so it definitely won't fire memory warning after 24Mb. It won't do that even after 200Mbs.

Comment: Max, I take it you are assuming that the iPhone is running no other software at the time? If so -- poor assumption.

Comment: MiiKL, implementing didReceiveLowMemoryWarning is not the "only good way to manage memory". We don't do that at all. Implementing viewDidUnload in all the correct places also works. Obviously a hybrid approach might also be appropriate. But your statement isn't accurate.

Comment: @occulus. You are right that didzreceiveMemoryWarning is not the only way to manage memory. The real way is to use I lazily and release it as you go. What I really meant was that it was the only way to manage critical memory situations. I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @Max. 20/24 Mb is recommended practice to take into account all other usage.

Comment: @Max. I got this from reading the "iPhone Programming: The big berd ranch guide", a very good book on iPhone programing. Here is the quote: "Overuse of graphical memory is typically the reason why an application receives a low memory warning. Apple suggests that you don't use more than 24MB of graphics memory". I wrote my answer from memory and will revise it to be more accurate.

Comment: @Max. Accept? Either my answer or the other one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know when it will fire. You don't know how much memory is being used by other apps running in the background, Safari keeping webpages, etc. Pandora might be streaming in the background and it might be using a significant amount of memory. Don't count on any single amount of memory. Load lazily, and release uneeded allocations in didRecieveMemoryWarning.
If your app requires a lot of memory, some game developers tell their users to restart the device before playing to ensure the most memory for the app, and best performance.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, can you tell me what lazy loading is please?

Comment: @likki Lazy loading is not loading a resource until you need it. For example if you need to load an image. But the image can't be seen until the user scrolls down, don't load it until the user scrolls down as it would take up memory resources unnecessarily.

Comment: lets say we have two views, user goes to view 2 only to comeback to view 1 very soon, however i do not want to reload view 1 as it would cause bad user experience and to do this cannot release object of view1. in this case how to deal with it?

Comment: @likki It's fine to keep view 1 alive. But if you get a didRecieveMemoryWarning while in view 2, kill view 1 then load it later.